# battery drainage question on HTC Sensation

Tags: htc

HTC Sensation Z710e is one of the phone I have used over years. I found out that this handset’s battery drains extreme fast and I tried to find out some ways to reduce the battery drainage and make battery performance better. I got a [replacement battery for Sensation](http://www.mpjbattery.com/bateria-para-htc/para-sensation-4g-z710e-g14.html) from a friend and this is helpful.

I think it probably because I are using the stock battery for too long time? it is also easily got hot now...so how long can a stock battery actually be used??

Comment: well it depends on the how you use the phone. Frequent charging is one of the ways the battery life is affected negatively.Also let the battery drain completely before you start charging.Do this atleast twice a month.It increases battery life. Also do not overcharge the phone.

Comment: Frequent charging does not noticably affect battery life of LiIo batteries, that's a myth. What does affect it is "running it low" (also called "deep discharge", or "complete drain"). So following your advice to *let the battery drain completely before you start charging* actually shortens its life. See also: [How frequently is it okay to let the battery discharge fully or as low as possible?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33704/16575) "Overcharging" is another myth, as the battery controller prevents such.

Answer (score 1):

Install a wakelock detector. Wakelocks don't allow your phone to conserve battery life like it's intended to. The detector will tell you which apps to uninstall. Something is probably pegging your phone processor or wifi.