# Charge Level Control

Tags: htc-incredible-s

Would there be any application or method of controlling the charge level and limiting it for example to start charging at 20% and stop charging at 80% ?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Lithium based batteries get better cycle usage if you don't use the full charge level.  If you normally use 50% then using 30-80% will give you more cycles then 50-100%. If you use the phone plugged in a lot (e.g. developing) then stopping the full 100% charge will help the battery life generally.  The long term life gets worse with charge level and temperature so fully charged and in use e.g. warm is a worst case state for battery life.

Comment: I've heard that about Lithium batteries, and I've also heard that it's an "old wives tale".  See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29073/battery-life-and-first-time-charging-on-li-ion-batteries-myth?newsletter=1&nlcode=36875%7c8c25.

Comment: The battery meter saying "100%" doesn't necessarily mean what it seems.  Check this article: http://phandroid.com/2010/12/25/your-smartphones-battery-gauge-is-lying-to-you-and-its-not-such-a-bad-thing/                   The signal indicator on a phone is similarly misleading, only worse.  The real reading is under about phone>status.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** to make a beep or push a notification when battery level is ouside your safety boundaries, so you can take an action by yourself (ie. un/plug the charger).

Go to [developer website](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/), where [Tasker Userguide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/index.html) can help you to set that task, [taking as context the State](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html) of your device.

The following image shows an example of configuring Tasker to take an action depending on battery state:

[image: Tasker in action]

Answer (score 1):

**Application:**
 **No**, as for an application to do this, the answer is no since charging on an Android phone is done by its hardware! The software has nothing to do with the actual charging of the phone! (This is why your phone is able to charge even when the OS is powered down)

**Method:**
 **No**, since the charging is not controlled by the software of your phone, this means it will be very difficult to stop your phone from charging (since there is no software modification that I can think of that will help... I could be wrong!)

**However**, as pointed out by [Francisco Alvarado](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/12677/francisco-alvarado) [**earlier**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59573/52084) you could create Tasker profiles to notify you about custom charge levels. Or if you are very paranoid about maintaining battery health you could *make Tasker prompt you before [automatically shutting down](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/O3ZtzpvtYxg)* (just a suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

You can hardwire it: 12 ohms in serial still makes the phone be recognized by the computer, yet slowly discharge.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well one way of doing it would be with a device such as Raspberry Pi or similar (perhaps with java installed on it). With an add on such as Laika it can control devices including relays which could turn on/off the power to a charger. Since Android to PC communication is available over USB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port then I'm guessing an app could talk to the fruity device, if not it could post to your own hosted web service. The app could then tell the device when to turn on the charger and when to turn it off according the the apps settings.

OK, a bit over the top and would need experimentation, but I think it could be done.

Lets hope that Android Marshmallow (or Maltesers or M&Ms or whatever it is) will have this built in for hardware that can support it.

Comment: It looks like RPi/Android USB communication is available, as it has been reported you can use this: http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=262