# how long can the battery in my new mobile stay idle till first use

Tags: battery

I bought a Samsung Galaxy 6 months ago. Have not used it yet nor have charged the battery atleast once. I am worried about the battery. Can i keep it idle two more months.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [How frequently is it okay to let the battery discharge fully or as low as possible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33704/16575) and [A: Although I was told to charge my Android device before first use, it was already charged. Ha…](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27868/16575) for this, which include corresponding hints. Some basic stuff here, though:

Wikipedia holds a [detailed article on Lithium-ion batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery). For your question, the answer is mentioned there as follows:

> **Li+ batteries have a self-discharge rate of approximately 5–10% per month,** compared to over 30% per month in common nickel metal hydride batteries, approximately 1.25% per month for Low Self-Discharge NiMH batteries and 10% per month in nickel-cadmium batteries. They last longer if not deeply discharged (depleted) before recharging. The smaller the depth of discharge, the longer the battery will last.
>
> **Batteries may last longer if not stored fully discharged. As the battery self-discharges over time, its voltage gradually reduces. When depleted below the low-voltage threshold of the protection circuit (2.4 to 2.9 V/cell, depending on chemistry) it will be disabled and cannot be further discharged further until recharged. It is recommended to store batteries at 40% charge level.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

From that you can deduce: If the manufacturer behaved responsibly (which we may assume), the battery was charged at about 40% when leaving the factory. Assuming it took at least a month to get to you (it was at store as well, so it should have taken that long or longer), and consider the fact you bought it 6 month ago, the battery wasn't charged for at least 7 months. Self-discharge rate, according to the article, is 5-10% per month -- so your battery is pretty empty now, and most likely already about to enter the "dangerous level" of deep-discharge.

**Conclusion:** You should at least check it twice a year (once every 6 month) and make sure to charge it up to ~40..50% when not using it.