# Should I accept 2,5 year old Samsung Galaxy replacement battery?

Tags: battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I've just bought a "brand new" replacement battery for my Galaxy Nexus phone. When on-line store's package arrived, I was more than surprised (actually, shocked!) to find out, that battery's manufature date is... **2011-12-29** (*assuming, that it is manufacture date, what is behind these [four Chinese symbols in bottom-left corner](http://mediaparts.pl/allegro_new/samsung/baterie/i9250/3.jpg) of Samsung Galaxy battery*)!

Should I even think about accepting this package and using battery with my phone? Or should I return it immediately to the shop?

I found [this great Izzy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46887/20449). If I get its meaning right, it seems, that my battery is in the "dangerous level" of deep-discharge for a long, long time. If not dead at all. And should not be used anymore.

Or maybe, I'm wrong, and Li-Ion batteries that are leaving manufacturer for the first time can be storred for over two and a half year without any noticeable influence on their condition of performance?

Or maybe, that four Chinese symbols does not mean battery's manufacture date? But, what else could they mean?

Even if battery condition is fine, do I have any chance, that it will last any longer that six months period, covered by warranty, if it spent over 2,5 year in manufacturer warehouse?

Comment: If I were you, I would return it back.

Comment: "Or maybe, that four Chinese symbols does not mean battery's manufacture date? But, what else could they mean?" If you had a photo where they were readable, it might be possible to answer.

Comment: @DanHulme Sorry, for that. Here you go. Maybe [this](http://www.acebattery.ca/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/cellbatt/c34.jpg), [this](http://cdn.shopclues.com/images/detailed/603/AAA10071071j_1381905850.jpg) or [this one](http://www.trait-tech.com/uploads/details/T-SSI9250-1__.jpg). Basically, I assume, this **is** a manufacture date. So, the question remains: can 2,5 year battery be of any worth, even if shop sells it as "brand new" and gives 6 months warranty on it?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing [confirmed Chinese translation](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9313/6282) of these four symbols (yes -- it **is** a manufacture date) with [Izzy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46887/20449), which states, that *Li+ batteries have a self-discharge rate of approximately 5–10% per month*, we end up with conclusion, that even with most optimistic scenario, Li-Ion batteries stored in store or warehouse without cyclic re-charge (which most likely never happened) **are completely dead after 20 months** at most.

Which is equivalent to less than two years. Which leads us to a conclusion, that 2,5 half year old Li-Ion batteries are completely useless and shouldn't be purchased nor used.

Comment: I bought a replacement Li-Ion battery for a PDA once and it was basically dead when I got it. The charge only lasted about 15 mins. It's sad. :(